# Open parameters [Android-Studio]

Tags: java, android, android-studio

sorry for my bad english i'm franch !

I have created an android studio project "Navigation Drawer Activity" and i want configure the menu on the left.
I want to open the parameters activity, but my code doesn't work !

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

 if (id == R.id.Settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Accueil_Parametres.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

No problem in the manifest.

can you help me ?
Thank you !

Comment: What does 'my code doesn't work' mean? You get an error message? Is `onNavigationItemSelected` called? Did you debug your code?

Comment: Hello, nothing happens when I click

Comment: Then you have to provide more information and code.